# Grep Shadow File Meaning

Tags: linux, grep, passwd

Will someone please help me what is the output of the following code?

```
egrep -v '.*:\*|:\!' /etc/shadow |awk -F: '{print $1}'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you try it?

It's a list of users who do have a password.
The other users have a `*` or `!` after the `name:` in the `/etc/shadow` file.

Comment: That means if there is a user which is not listed in the output; therefore it is not associated with password, right?

Comment: That's right. The unlisted users are used to run services.

Answer (score 1):

prints the users of /etc/shadow files (first column)

Answer (score 1):

This command extracts a list of usernames from the /etc/shadow file. The /etc/shadow file stores the encrypted passwords of the users on the system and some additional properties.

The first part of the command `egrep` filters out the users who do not have a password set - so this will be the user accounts used for certain services.

The second part `awk` prints the first column of output from the `egrep` command - the columns are separated by a `:` character as specified by the `-F`. The first column of output contains the usernames.

Answer (score 1):

Explanation :

```
    egrep    - Search the pattern with using regular expression 
    -v       - Invert of matching pattern that mean matched pattern will not executed 
  '.*:\*|:\!'- That mean Any character and colon occur then the exact * found not
               any  charater of star ( For example User only password maintain 
               other than password field contain * .
     awk -F: - Set the delimiter is ":"
'{print $1}' - print the first column .
```

The password field contain encrypted password that the row will printed else * occur in the password filed that will not match.

Answer (score 1):

There are no need at all to use `egrep` here, `awk` can do it all:

```
awk -F: '$2!~/[*!]/ {print $1}' /etc/shadow
```

And as other points out, this list all user that does not contain `*` nor `!` in second field.
This will give all user with password.